# lighting issues

Tags: camera, lighting

I'm using a camera to take images in Blender, but the lighting in the scene doesn't remain consistent with the sun light I set up.  It changes based on where the camera is located so that areas that shouldn't be lit are.

eg:

[image]

Moving the camera forwards:

[image]

moving the camera to the another side of the building

[image]

How can I fix this lighting so that it uses my sun light, and just lights from one direction, regardless of the viewport or camera angle?

Please ask me if I've not been clear enough to clarify. I'm not sure how else to communicate this.

Here's a link to my blend:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/160TOtAbp_f4_WpkmAm3NanIdaYd7dAnF/view?usp=sharing

My shaders outside the grass are set up with some varient of this:
[image]

Comment: Are you using camera coordinates or any extremely strong normal maps in these shader node graphs?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. I have used a colour ramp to get a flat shading, using a constant ramp.

Comment: This is interesting, but not something I've seen before.  If you can [edit] your post with more information maybe someone can help.

Comment: Sure Ill add in some shader nodes and the blend file

Comment: If anybody wants more info please ask me some questions, im not really sure what additional information I could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a large sphere around your scene to cast the sky color, and this shadow on the ground is the sphere's shadow.  It is, for some reason, only visible a certain distance out from the camera.

In any case, you can select the 'Sky' sphere, go to the material settings and set the *Shadow Mode* to *None* and the issue is solved.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Allen!

Comment: No problem :) It's a really interesting aesthetic